# How to add featured thumbnail into import XML using URL image?

Tags: import

I would like to use an external image link to set the post's featured image in the XML. It is possible?

```
<item>
    <title>title1</title>
    <pubdate>2013-02-20 10:33:58</pubdate>
    <dc:creator>
    <![CDATA[ David Jennings ]]>
    </dc:creator>
    <guid ispermalink="false">http://wordpress/?p=1234</guid>
    <description>
    <title>Title</title>
    </description> 
    <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[ABCD]]>
    </content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded>
    <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>1234</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date>2013-02-20 10:33:00</wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt>2013-02-20 10:33:00</wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
    <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name>title1</wp:post_name>
    <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <category domain="category" nicename="blog"> <![CDATA[ blog ]]> </category>
    <wp:postmeta>

    <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[888888]]></wp:meta_value>

    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
```

I would like to use the image URL here:

```
    <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[888888]]></wp:meta_value>
```

Comment: featured images are stored on posts as attachment IDs not URLs, so you'd need an attachment post to reference, you can't put a URL in the `thumbnail_id` value. Why do you want this and what problem are you trying to solve? If this is so that local imports can still use production images then there are lots of better and easier solutions to that

Comment: I have a static HTML website and I need to convert it to WP. 
I read content of 500 pages with Simple HTML DOM and generate an XML. 
The HTML pages have futured images, I would like to include this XML to import and place as a featured image.


I thought about including the post ID for the attachment and pointing it in the post, but could that cause a conflict in WP?

Comment: you would need to generate attachment files and give them IDs then use those IDs. You're best generating a WXR export of a very small site to see how it's bundling media. WP will offer to download and create local copies of any media on import. I'd also suggest limiting your XML to 100 posts and having multiple files to avoid timing out the import